# Error writing to OrcNewOutputFormat using MapR MultipleOutputs

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce, amazon-emr

We reading data from ORC files and writing it back to ORC and Parquet format using MultipleOutputs. Our job is Map only and does not have a reducer.
We are getting following errors in some cases which fails the entire job. I think both the errors are related but not sure why those don't come for every job. 
Let me know if more information is required.

```
Error: java.lang.RuntimeException: Overflow of newLength. smallBuffer.length=1073741824, nextElemLength=300947

Error: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1000
    at org.apache.orc.impl.writer.StringTreeWriter.writeBatch(StringTreeWriter.java:70)
    at org.apache.orc.impl.writer.StructTreeWriter.writeRootBatch(StructTreeWriter.java:56)
    at org.apache.orc.impl.WriterImpl.addRowBatch(WriterImpl.java:546)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.orc.WriterImpl.flushInternalBatch(WriterImpl.java:297)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.orc.WriterImpl.close(WriterImpl.java:334)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.orc.OrcNewOutputFormat$OrcRecordWriter.close(OrcNewOutputFormat.java:67)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.MultipleOutputs$RecordWriterWithCounter.close(MultipleOutputs.java:375)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.MultipleOutputs.close(MultipleOutputs.java:574)


Error: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.lang.System.arraycopy(Native Method)
    at org.apache.orc.impl.DynamicByteArray.add(DynamicByteArray.java:115)
    at org.apache.orc.impl.StringRedBlackTree.addNewKey(StringRedBlackTree.java:48)
    at org.apache.orc.impl.StringRedBlackTree.add(StringRedBlackTree.java:60)
    at org.apache.orc.impl.writer.StringTreeWriter.writeBatch(StringTreeWriter.java:70)
    at org.apache.orc.impl.writer.StructTreeWriter.writeRootBatch(StructTreeWriter.java:56)
    at org.apache.orc.impl.WriterImpl.addRowBatch(WriterImpl.java:546)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.orc.WriterImpl.flushInternalBatch(WriterImpl.java:297)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.orc.WriterImpl.close(WriterImpl.java:334)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.orc.OrcNewOutputFormat$OrcRecordWriter.close(OrcNewOutputFormat.java:67)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.MultipleOutputs$RecordWriterWithCounter.close(MultipleOutputs.java:375)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.MultipleOutputs.close(MultipleOutputs.java:574)
```

Comment: Did you found the reason for this ?

Answer (score 2):

In my case the solution was to change `orc.rows.between.memory.checks` (or `spark.hadoop.orc.rows.between.memory.checks`) from `5000` (default value) to `1`.

Because it seems like ORC writer cannot handle adding abnormally large rows to a stripe.

The value can probably be further adjusted to achieve better safety-performance balance.